# How to compare String with Int

Tags: java, int

```
public static void main(String[] args){     
    String buf;

    buf = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1, 2 or 3");

    if (buf == 1) {
        Begin2();}//if a
    if (buf == 2) {
        Main.Begin6();}//if b
    if (buf == 3) {
        Main.Begin7();}//if b
}
```

I have this code, but if cant invoke any of Begin methods...

Comment: `buf.equals("1")`, `buf.equals("2")`, `buf.equals("3")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
if("1".equals(buf)) {
    Begin2();
} else if ("2".equals(buf)) {
    Main.Begin6();
} else if ("3".equals(buf)) {
    Main.Begin7();
}
```

or

```
switch(buf) {
    case "1": Begin2(); break;
    case "2": Main.Begin6(); break;
    case "3": Main.Begin7(); break;
    default: break;
}
```

would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

To convert to an integer, use `Integer.valueOf(String)`:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(buf) == 1) {
```

A better option is to use the method from `JOptionPane` that asks for input with given selections. This way you would force the user to input 1, 2 or 3, and at the same there would be no need to convert to an integer.

```
Integer result = (Integer) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "1, 2 or 3", "title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Integer[]{1,2,3}, 1);

if (result == 1) {
  ... 
} else if (result == 2) {
  ...
} else if (result == 3) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert it to an Integer using `Integer.parseInt(buf)` (best way)
2. Use `"3".equals(buf)` (ugly).
3. Keep as string and use `switch` (if you are in Java 7 >=) or `if` using equals method

Some says that you can just keep it as String and use a `equals` or `switch`. Yes it works, the fact to convert it to `int` **maybe** here is a bit excessive and it will avoids you a possible exception in case of wrong input

Comment: OP could also use a `switch` statement, which would be the same for int and string, so no `.equals` needed, and no `parseInt` needed.

Comment: Yes, but only with Java 7 >=. Most of time i prefer to convert the values in their correct type

Comment: If the user enters a string option 1 would give some ugly errors. I prefer option 2 or `buf.equals("3")`

Comment: It is already a String, just use `.equals()`. In reality, I doubt the numbers 1, 2, and 3 mean anything in the context of this program. They should probably be replaced with constants that say that the options do. (e.g. `String DISPLAY_MENU = 1;`,`String ADD_ITEM = 2`, etc..

Comment: Because I don't like when String (or any other type) is used when other type could be used. If it's an Integer it should be an int in the code too. But it depends of course

Comment: @Charlie `"3".equals(buf)` avoids `NullPointerException` if `buf` is `null`, that's why you see `"3".equals(buf)` and not `buf.equals("3")`

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(buff);
if(value == 1){...}

else if(value == 2){...}

else if(value == 3){...}
```

Comment: does not compile, have to catch that exception

Comment: @HunterMcMillen `NumberFormatException` is an `UncheckedException`, so you don't have to explicitly catch it.

Comment: You do if you don't want your program to crash unexpectedly.  If I enter an 'a' for instance.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I was only answering the  _"does not compile"_. Of course you should check the validity of the input.

Comment: true, my mistake. I thought this was a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Different ways for doing this task:

`Integer.parseInt("3")`       // This will return an integer value

or you can use the `.equals()` of class String